# Widget to visually select time ranges on a graph?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, widget

I'm graphing spectral data and I want to be able to graph my data, and using a slider, select portions of the graph and display the times I have selected. Just like highlighting a word in a paragraph, but I want the selected time range to also display and save somewhere in a list.

I've tried using spanselector, but it doesn't seem to work with spectral data. I can't get it to graph times, data, and then flux all on one graph.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.